# Mongoose aggregation: How to display the result from aggregation with ejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

How can I get the result from mongoose aggregation and display it with ejs?

This is my code:

```
Record.aggregate(
    [
        {
        $group: 
        {
            _id: { month: { $month: "$date"}, year: { $year: "$date"} },
            totalExpense: { $sum: "$amountExpense"},
            totalIncome: { $sum: "$amountIncome"},
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
       },
       { "$project": {
        "total": { "$subtract": [ "$totalIncome", "$totalExpense" ] }
     }},
     {
       $out: "total"
     }     
    ]), function(err, results) {
      console.log(results);
      res.json(results);
  }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `res.render()` instead?

Comment: The above comment is basically what you want, however you also should not be using [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/). This pipeline stage redirects ALL output to the named collection. So the `results` in your callback function will not contain anything whilst that pipeline stage is in use.